# How i can Hide a registration page after the user login in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication

i have a website with master page that contain Tab Container in this tab container i have some links such home,log in,registration and so others

my problem is how to hide log in and registration pages when user log in and show log out and update personal data forms in staid of log in and registration

note that all the pages are in `ContentPlaceHolder`

place help me with this problem

Comment: where are your `login` and `registration` links located ?? In navigation . Show us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code its unable to give what you want but I suggest:

1) Maintain login status in Session.

2)Check Session.

```
if(Session["LoginStatus"] = true)
{
   YourTabcontainerID.Tabs[1].Visible = false;
   //Your Login/logout Link Logic goes here
}
else
    YourTabcontainerID.Tabs[1].Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write an if-statement where you check if there is a session started. That if-statement has to be placed on the location where you create the "tabs"